# Shows an error zsh: segmentation fault . How to change?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

i try to create a program that displays its given arguments.
when i start a compiled programm, 
i write test1 test2 test3 test4

it displays:

```
-

test1
test2
test3
test4
zsh: segmentation fault  ./a.out test1 test2 test3 test4

-
```

Code:

```
int     main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    int i;
    int j;
    i = 0;
    j = 1;
    if (argc >= 1)
    {
        while (argv[j][i] != '\0')
        {
            while (argv[j][i] != '\0')
            {
                ft_putchar(argv[j][i]);
                i++;
            }
            j++;
            i = 0;
            ft_putchar('\n');
        }
    }
    return (0);
}
```

What should i change in my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't stop your while loop and end up accessing somewhere you shouldn't.

argv is an array of string which size is "argc", so "j" should not be equal or greater than "argc".

But in reality, argv is an array of size "argc + 1", the last value being NULL.
So you could simply loop until "argv[j]" is NULL.

Answer (score 2):

When `argc` is `3` for example argv[3] is `NULL` so your `segfault` is accessing `argv[3][i]`
Loop instead `for (j=0; j<argc; j++)`

If for *some* reason you can't use a `for` loop this code should help;

```
int     main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    int i;
    int j;
    i = 0;
    j = 1;
    if (argc >= 1)
    {
        while (argv[j])
        {
            while (argv[j][i] != '\0')
            {
                ft_putchar(argv[j][i]);
                i++;
            }
            j++;
            i = 0;
            ft_putchar('\n');
        }
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: given the function name "ft_putchar", this is a student a the "42" school that don't allow for loop. Yes .... I know ....

Comment: @Tom's Wow never heard of such a thing.  I suppose he could change the first `while` loop to something like `while (argv[j])`

Comment: Yes ... Sadly, this madness come from "Epitech". And the shcool "Etna" and "42" are like copy/paste of Epitech. A lot of ink have bleed over this senseless rule, and it appear that forbidding the for loop is because some student abused it by making monstruous for loop (and because "it's possible with a while loop, so why it bother you ?" ...). Yes ... I know ....